# Web Routing for IIS6 and II7 Classic Mode? *NOT* MVC

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, web-config, url-routing

According to the msdn.microsoft.com site, .NET 3.5 Routing should work under IIS6 and II7 in classic mode.  I've made the mods to the web.config file and tested under IIS7 integrated mode and it's working great.

I'd love to keep IIS7 Integrated, but my webhost is still just IIS6 (with .net 3.5).

So... has anyone gotten this to work?

I'm currently getting 404 errors and the only switch is going from IIS7 integrated to IIS7 classic on the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joy of the internet... keep searching and rephrasing and you find it yourself. :)

For posterity, the answer is to enable a wildcard mapping that routes all requests through ASP.NET ISAPI.

Comment: IIS Manager >> Sites >> Your Website >> Handler Mappings >> Actions >> Add Wildcard ScriptMap >> enter: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll

Comment: here is what microsoft says about that : *“Be aware that this option causes IIS to intercept every request made against the web server. This includes requests for images, classic ASP pages, and HTML pages. Therefore, enabling a wildcard script map to ASP.NET does have performance implications.”*